# jQuery add class does not work

Tags: jquery

Okay so basically when the page loads, I want to have a class called "active" added to my id #navHome. However, the class does not show. My HTML part is an include so I don't know if it has to do with that or if I just did something stupid wrong?

This is what I have:

HTML part:

```
<ul id="navList">
    <li><a href="index.php" title="Home" id="navHome">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="About" id="navAbout">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.php" title="Portfolio" id="navPortfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Contact" id="navContact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS part:

```
.active {
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold';
    color: #3fe3ab;
    background: url('../design/images/navLiner.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#navHome').addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Does anything come up in the console?

Comment: Works here `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/cf4GD/ .. check if you properly included jQuery.

Comment: You don't have more than one element with the ID #navHome do you? And what do you mean by "My HTML part is an include"?

Comment: Yes jQuery is properly included since my other jQuery codes work. I don't have more elements with that same id. I mean that I used a PHP <?php include_once('includes/nav.php'); ?> in which the HTML is (it's not in the "actual" page).

Comment: Be sure that jQuery is being included before you execute your javascript.

Comment: Edit: I'm not quite sure what you mean? I put the script in my header and the include in my body but nothing shows up? I tried changing the order too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the css is referenced properly? If you change your nav.php file to manually add the active class to your link, does it work?

Comment: Mhh no this doesn't work either. So it must be something with the CSS I guess but I really don't understand what.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, right click the home button and select "inspect element". See if the class is added. Should look like:

```
<ul id="navList">
    <li><a href="index.php" title="Home" id="navHome" class="active">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="About" id="navAbout">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.php" title="Portfolio" id="navPortfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Contact" id="navContact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you see the class is added, then the problem is with the CSS. If you don't see the added class, then it's a problem with your jQuery. From there, you should be able to fix it yourself.

If your unable to resolve should be able to help you better by narrowing down the problem. Is it an issue with your jQuery or CSS? Reply back with your results so we can further assist you if you need it.

Comment: Thanks you for the tip. Yes, the class is showing. However, the results of it don't show. I tried adding !important to the CSS, and then font-family and color plus the background do show. I don't think this is the correct solutions though? Something must have been overriding the style.

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed I still had the class added manually. jQuery does not add the class when inspecting the element in Chrome.